# Rendering Height Map, glDrawElements Issues

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, terrain

I've got this class which I'm developing which I hope to eventually use to draw a terrain map. The code currently looks like this:

```
IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(3);

 int vHandle = ib.get(0);
 int cHandle = ib.get(1);
 int iHandle = ib.get(2);

FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(19);
FloatBuffer cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(18);
ShortBuffer iBuffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(6);


TerrainFlat(float x,float y,float z, float[] input /* here is where I want to put my draw distance stuff*/){

    this.Map = input;

    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.z=z;


}

@Override
public void initilize(){

    float[] vertexData = {50, 20, 100,      50, -20, 100,      10, -20, 100,             -10, -20, 100,     -50, -20, 100,     -50, 20, 100};
    float[] colorData = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 };
    short[] indexData = {0,1,2,3,4,5};

    vBuffer.put(vertexData);
    vBuffer.flip();


    cBuffer.put(colorData);
    cBuffer.flip();


    iBuffer.put(indexData);
    iBuffer.flip();


}



@Override
public void draw(){

                   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glGenBuffersARB(ib);
  vHandle = ib.get(0);
  cHandle = ib.get(1);
  iHandle = ib.get(2);

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
  glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride */3 << 2, 0L);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cHandle);
  glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
  glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride */3 << 2, 0L);

 glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iHandle);
 glBufferDataARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, /* elements */6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0L);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
  glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);


}

@Override
public void destroy(){
    ib.put(0, vHandle);
  ib.put(1, cHandle);
  ib.put(2, iHandle);
  glDeleteBuffersARB(ib);
}
```

Now I'm wondering if I can bind my data in the initilize function, instead of the Draw function, in order to move the declarations:

```
FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(19);
FloatBuffer cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(18);
ShortBuffer iBuffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(6);
```

into the initilize function, or at the very least after the terrain functions so I can control their lengths via a draw distance function.

UPDATE:
I change my code based on the answer given (thank you btw) to this:

```
@Override
public void initilize(){


    float[] vertexData = {50, 20, 100,      50, -20, 100,      10, -20, 100,             -10, -20, 100,     -50, -20, 100,     -50, 20, 100};
    float[] colorData = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 };
    short[] indexData = {0,1,2,3,4,5};

    vBuffer.put(vertexData);
    vBuffer.flip();


    cBuffer.put(colorData);
    cBuffer.flip();


    iBuffer.put(indexData);
    iBuffer.flip();

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
  glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);


  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cHandle);
  glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);


  glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iHandle);
  glBufferDataARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);



}

@Override
public void setUp(float posX, float posY, float posZ){



}

@Override
public void draw(){

                   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glGenBuffersARB(ib);
  vHandle = ib.get(0);
  cHandle = ib.get(1);
  iHandle = ib.get(2);

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride */3 << 2, 0L);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cHandle);
   glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride */3 << 2, 0L);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iHandle);

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, /* elements */6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0L);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
  glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);


}
```

This executes but fails to draw anything, I do not have FACE_CULL enabled either.

Comment: `Now I'm wondering if I can bind my data in the initilize function` so... did you try it?

Comment: I did, but its led to more issues hence the update above.

Comment: I'd tried it in various ways before asking as well, and it has the same issue: nothing drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the buffers before drawing (except you are always drawing the same buffers) but you can move the `glBufferData` calls to your initialize function.

Something like this should work:

```
public void initilize() {
   ...
   // set data for vHandle
   glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
   glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
   glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride */3 << 2, 0L);

   // ... setup other handles
   ...
}


public void draw() {
   ...
   glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);

   // ... bind other buffers

   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, /* elements */6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0L);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I just moved the code around and now I have this error:
Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLChecks.ensureArrayVBOenabled(GLChecks.java:93)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertexPointer(GL11.java:2680)
 at gameengine1_0.TerrainFlat.initilize(TerrainFlat.java:71)
 at gameengine1_0.GameEngine1_0.main(GameEngine1_0.java:225)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I moved the pointers into the Draw(); but now it fails to draw anything despite running.

Comment: @micha: why would you bind the VBO for drawing? The currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is totally irrrelevant for drawing.